# AT commande mode with HC-05 FC-114 bluetooth module

Tags: bluetooth, at-command, arduino-uno

i am having a problem with my bluetooth module, am using an HC-05 FC-114 where there is no key pin but there is an EN pin. I couldn't use it to get the AT mode i tried to follow many tutorials but using the EN pin instead of the key pin but it doesn't work! how can i get into the AT command mode? Any help please!

Comment: This question is way to unclear. You need to 1) at the very least give links to the manufacturer documentation for this device. 2) Link to some concrete example of these tutorials you talk about. 3) Provide a picture/drawing of exactly how this device is connected and what it is connected to.

Comment: Am using this bluetooth HC-05 FC-114 here is some informations about it:
http://abc-rc.pl/templates/images/files/995/1425483439-hc-06-datasheet.pdf
This is one of the tutorials that i followed but it doesn't work; http://www.martyncurrey.com/hc-05-fc-114-and-hc-06-fc-114-part-2-basic-at-commands/

Comment: The HC-05 starts in datamode. You have to send it the escape sequence wich is $$$ without linefeed or carriage return.

Comment: using the same connection??
– Arduino D2 to BT TX
– Arduino D3 to voltage divider and then to BT RX
– Arduino 5v out to BT vcc in
– GND to GND

Comment: because it didn't work like that i tried to sent this sequence but nothing changed it is still blinking too fast and not responding
i pressed the BT button for nearly 3s it started blinking one blink once every 2s i sent this sequence but still not responding